# Multiple Markers for Google Maps API V3 With Literal Asp.Net Control

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to add Marker in Google Maps (API V3) ,
I use XML file for store locations

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string locations = "";
            string lastlat = "", lastlng = "";

            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Map.xml"));
            var query = from st in xmlDoc.Descendants("Position")
                        select st;

            foreach (var p in query)
            {
                lastlat = p.Element("Latitude").Value;
                lastlng = p.Element("Longitude").Value;
                locations += "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(" 
                    + p.Element("Latitude").Value + "," 
                    + p.Element("Longitude").Value + "),info:\"" 
                    + p.Element("Name").Value + "\",title:\""
                    + p.Element("Name").Value + "\",map: map});marker.setMap(map)";
            }
            Label1.Text = locations;
            js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>function initialize() { var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" + lastlat + "," + lastlng + "); var myOptions = {zoom: 16, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP } var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);" + locations + "marker.setMap(map);}</script>";
        }
```

and this code

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <asp:Literal ID="js" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <div id="map" style="width:995px;height:600px;"></div>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

but do not show map in webpage!!!

This gives two error

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
    Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined
```

Comment: have you referenced the google maps api javascript file.

Comment: @roughnex I have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon after

```
var myOptions = {zoom: 16, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
```

I bet it'll work if you add that in.